# discord.py - How can I change the amount of XP a user gets to earn levels? (on message event, leveling)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a leveling system. I got the leaderboard to work, the XP system, and the level-up message working. I want the owner of a server to be able to choose how much XP the server gets. The default is 4, and I want the other user to change it, like 7 XP for example. I am not talking about how to change the amount of XP through the code, but a command. When a server owner executes the command, it changes the amount of XP for the server **only.** Since I'm very new to discord.py, I have **no clue** how to change it from another command. Does anyone have any help for me? Please and thank you!! :)

entire code:

```
message_cooldown = {}

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        # Check if the user is in the cooldown dictionary
        if message.author.id in message_cooldown:
            current_time = time.time()
            last_message_time = message_cooldown[message.author.id]

            # Check if the user's cooldown has expired (0.5 seconds cooldown)
            if current_time - last_message_time < 1:
                return

        with open('level.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        await update_data(users, message.author, message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel, message.guild)

        # Update the last message time for the user
        message_cooldown[message.author.id] = time.time()

        with open('level.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)




async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))
  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send(':fire: {} has leveled up to **Level {}!**'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end

@bot.command(aliases = ['rank','lvl'])
async def level(ctx,member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        user = ctx.message.author
        # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
        with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
        exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']

        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP " ,color = discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(name = ctx.author, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar.url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    else:
      # specify the encoding as utf-8 when opening the file
      with open('level.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
          users = json.load(f)
      lvl = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['level']
      exp = users[str(ctx.guild.id)][str(member.id)]['experience']
      embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Level {}'.format(lvl), description = f"{exp} XP" ,color = discord.Color.green())
      embed.set_author(name = member, icon_url = member.avatar.url)

      await ctx.send(embed = embed)

@bot.tree.command(name="leaderboard", description="View the top 10 people who has the most levels in a server.")
async def hello(ctx: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Leaderboard for {ctx.guild.name}", color=discord.Colour.blurple())
    with open('level.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    data = data[str(ctx.guild.id)]
    sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda item:item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)
    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member.display_name} (@{member.name})", value=f"**Level {bal['level']}**\n{bal['experience']} XP", inline=False)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.user.name}", icon_url = ctx.user.avatar.url)
        if pos+1 > 9:
            break 
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

JSON file example:

```
{
  "757383943116030074": {
    "123456789012345678": {
      "experience": 0,
      "level": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to your question**

You could add a `settings.json` to your bot and store all of the settings of a guild (server) in there, just like you store the member data in the `level.json` file. Your code could read that file everytime and gets the according amount of XP, set by the owner. For that you would have to add another command that will set this

**Advise for making your life easier**

But as a general advise, storing such data in a json file is called bad practice, as json files easily get corrupted during writing by exceptions in your code. This is making dataloss fairly easy.

I suggest that you have a look into the [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) file database system, the general python libary for it ( [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) ) and especially the [aiosqlite](https://aiosqlite.omnilib.dev/en/latest/?badge=latest) library which is the one you want to use in asynchronous environments like discord.py, as the normal library will block your code during queries.

In addition you should have a look into the [general concept of a database](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-database-concepts/) to get an idea what databases are used for, as they will help you to make storing masses of data alot easier.

If you have any further questions about this or something is unclear, don't be afraid of asking! I'll be helping you as much as I can.

Comment: I seriously don't want to rewrite the entire code with sqlite3, it would be a pain to do so.

Comment: Then just follow the first thing, make a settings.json and store the guild settings in that and read it

Comment: If my answer helped you I‘d appreciate it if you could mark it a correct answer